# Is it possible to access all Android files from your computer over USB?

Tags: android, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero, and I am going to try to create a script that automatically downloads all documents, pictures, messages, etc... when a device is plugged in. Before I start doing research, is this even possible? If so, what should I look into before I start working on this?

Comment: Check if device connected: "adb devices". Pull files from phone: "adb pull /sdcard/ ./"

Comment: It is possible, given we are talking about media files and app based text files only if your phone is rooted.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, I believe this a possible task.

[Here](https://media.blackhat.com/bh-dc-11/Stavrou-Wang/BlackHat_DC_2011_Stavrou_Zhaohui_USB_exploits-Slides.pdf) is a good read on exploiting USB, this could be useful for your project.

[Here](http://www.eeherald.com/section/design-guide/esmod14.html) is another good read on USB interface. You might be interested on the handshake section.